# how to run @schedule on the current running thread in spring boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, scheduled-tasks

We have a method that I want to run in current thread after a certain interval.

If I use @scheduled in spring boot it may or may not run that method on different thread. How we can run this method on same thredpool.

We need this to check TCP client connection after certain period if its connected then its OK if its not we need to close the connection. Client is not keepalive message enabled. We can not change client. Client continuously sending data. If we do not close the connections number of connections keeps increasing.

Do we have any thing like this in java.

I tried TimerTask & Taskscheduler but both run on a separate thread.

PS: I am new on writing schedulers.

Comment: could you show your code ? Have you followed any tutorial ?

Comment: Hi, 
I didn't think it can be achieved this way. A scheduled task is launched regardless of what is executed in the same time. If you launch it in your spring boot thread, it will froze your server due this non-asynchronized task.

Comment: Hi @TimWeber do you have any suggestion by which we can achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
Thread.sleep()
```

for some time then you can do your check for **TCP Connection code** after that sleep time

Comment: We can not use Thred.sleep() we want some other code to execute to process data.